# Does this function send ether from the contract or from the message sender?

Tags: solidity, security

Solidity newbie here...:

```
 function transfer(address payable to, address sender) public onlyadmin {
         to.transfer(msg.value);

     }
```

what I want to achieve is sending from the contract's balance so I guess this.balance should be the correct way and not msg.value? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transfer moves money from contract's account to the beneficiary one, while balance is a lookup function that takes one arbitrary address as input and gives back its balance.

`msg.value` is the amount of Ether send along with the message. 
If you want to send all money of the contract you have to write something like that:

```
function f(address payable beneficiary) public {
    beneficiary.transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

If you write something like that:

```
function f(address payable beneficiary) payable public {
    beneficiary.transfer(msg.value);
}
```

Whenever, the msg.sender sends `msg.value` Wei to the contract. The latter transfers the money to the beneficiary. In this case the smart contract is a broker that gives the received money to the beneficiary one.